# How to hit multiple pages in sequential order || JMeter

Tags: controller, request, jmeter

I need to hit multiple pages in sequential order.

The sample pattern what I am looking exactly:

Thread group contain: 5 users

Pages:

1. Homepage
2. Page1
3. Page2
4. Page3

Now every user will follow these four pages sequentially. like below format:

- User1:

  ```
  homepage -> page1 -> page2 -> page3
  ```
- User2:

  ```
  Homepage -> page1 -> page2 -> page3
  ```
- User5:

  ```
  ...
  ```

How can I do this in `Jmeter`?

Comment: so you just put samplers one after the other and they will run sequentially. What's the problem?

Comment: @KirilS. I tried by using samplers but it is not executing sequentially. It is executing page1 5times and page2  5times and soon..

Comment: yes, it looks like you are simply misinterpreting results. But regardless, you have to provide question with more details in order for anyone to help you. As it stands, it's anyone's guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running samplers in sequential order is something JMeter does **by default**, each thread (virtual user) is absolutely independent and once started it executes samplers upside down (or according to the logic controllers).

You can easily verify this using [__threadNum() function](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733739-Using-JMeter-Functions-Part-II) (which returns the number of current thread) as your request prefix or postfix:

[image: JMeter Order of Running Samplers]

The actual order will depend on ramp-up period you define in [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) and sample result [Elapsed Time](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html), however as you can see, each virtual user starts with `Homepage` and ends with `Page 3`

Answer (score 0):

You are putting the request in an order and running it with 5 threads. So, in view results you will **not** get the sequence due to parallel execution but each thread is running it in the same order/sequence as defined in the test plan. This is what is generally expected.

If you want sequence then give 1 thread and 5 loops. This is not you want to do as it make no sense for performance test.
[image]

Or you can you use bzm - Concurrency Thread Group as shown below:-

[image]

[image]

Above screenshots are just for clarification and I hope you don't want to achieve this.